# match time zone of mysql with php server

Tags: php, mysql

`php` server time from `echo date_default_timezone_get ( void );` function is  this  `Asia/Karachi`

And `mysql` time zone from `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%time_zone'` query is this 
     `system_time_zone : CST`

now how can I change MysQl time zone to match with my php server time.

Due to this difference the `php date()` and `mysql current_timestamp` are giving different results.

Comment: For God's sake, don't just upvote the comment, cast actual votes!

Answer (score 1):

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Karachi';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your database

```
SET time_zone = 'Asia/Karachi';
```